# How to get ASUS Smart Connect to favour 2.4Ghz to a greater extent

Tags: wireless-networking, asus

I have a case where in one room of my house my laptop keeps trying to connect via 5 GHz and it goes terribly. Frequent dropouts on 5 and the 2.4 network goes fine.

The [Smart Connect documentation](https://www.asus.com/nz/support/FAQ/1012132/) does not provide advice on this issue. Ideally, the documentation would come with concrete instructions for tweaks to deal with common situations like mine.

So, how do I tweak the advanced ASUS Smart Connect settings to either 1) stop these dropouts on 5 GHz (are they a result of poor connection or Smart Connect malfunctioning?) or 2) get the network to stick to 2.4 GHz on my laptop when 5 GHz has poor connection quality?

Comment: Which model are your laptop and its wireless adapter and the router?

Comment: Man configuring that in the router LOOKS more complicated & would affect other WiFi devices in the house that work fine on 5GHz to only use 2.4GHz. I'm thinking you tweak a setting in your laptop as a first effort. I'd do the following: 1)give us the info harrymc suggests; 2)update your wifi driver; 3)in device manager right-click wifi, properties, Advanced make note of the settings then tweak some to see if you can force laptop to use 2.4GHz

Comment: I am using a Dell 5550 Laptop running Ubuntu 21.10. The router is x2 ASUS Xt8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is normal that the 5 GHz network is faster but its range is shorter. Your PC is probably just far enough away from the router so that the 5 GHz gets too weak to work stable.

- You can simply use two different SSIDs for the 2.4 GHz and the 5 GHz networks (setting at your router), and never connect the 5 GHz SSID from your laptop.
- Also, it looks like the whole idea of the SmartConnect utility is to *mix* usage between the two as possible; if you don't want that, simple don't use SmartConnect.
- Third, there are settings up to which quality level ('-nn db') the SmartConnect should try to use each network; you can change this setting a bit up for the 5 GHz network, so it wouldn't be used if it is too weak.

Even if the 5 GHz sometimes works, overall you're probably better off to only use the 2.4 GHz, and have a stable connection. Consider that the higher speed is probably only theoretical, as the connection out to the internet is slower than even the 2.4 GHz speed - don't look at the nominal speed that your ISP sells you, but the speed your connection partner delivers on its server! For example, even if you have a 10 GBit/s line, Netflix only serves you 50 Mbit/s)

Comment: this answer really only glances at answering the question on the third bullet point. Most of your advice is very easy to find in other places.

Of course, for the most part I do want to use smartconnect and not have to reconnect my 40 devices to the wifi network if I change to multiple SSIDs. When I'm closer to the router, I do want it to use 5 GHz. I tried fiddling with the nn db numbers but it doesn't seem to be working.

Answer (score 0):

My answer is intended for the laptop, rather than the router,
and is based on the post
[How to set wifi driver settings to prefer 5 GHz channel above 2.4 GHz](https://askubuntu.com/a/631329/963426),
except that I reversed the advice so as to prefer the 2.4 GHz channel.

You first need to get the name of your network interface.
You may use for that `iwconfig`. It's assumed here to be `wlan0`.

Run:

```
$ iwlist wlan0 scanning | grep -C3 <name of your network>
```

(For some computers `C3` may need to be replaced by `C5` or else.)

You should find 2 entries for the network, for example:

```
Cell XX - Address: 11:11:11:11:11:11 // This will be different in your machine
ESSID: "name of your network" // This will be different on your machine
Protocol: IEEE 802.11bgn
Mode: Master
Frequency: 2.437 Ghz

--

Cell XX - Address: 22:22:22:22:22:22 // This will be different on your machine
ESSID: "name of your network // This will be different on your machine
Protocol: IEEE 802.11AC
Mode: Master
Frequency: 5.18 Ghz
```

- BSSID for the 5Ghz Network, in this example: 22:22:22:22:22:22
- BSSID for the 2.4 Ghz Network, in this example: 11:11:11:11:11:11

Now what you do is:

1. click on 'Network Connections'
2. 'Edit Connections...'
3. [Select your network connection] (there could be 2 entries, any will do)
4. Click Edit
5. Go to 'Wi-Fi' or 'Wireless' Tab
6. Click the BSSID Dropdown
7. Select the BSSID Matching the 2.4 Ghz Network (11:11:11:11:11:11 in this example)
8. Switch to the 'General Tab'
9. Make sure to check the checkbox that is labelled: 'Automatically connect to this network when it is available'
10. Rename the Connection Name (not the SSID) to 'your network name'_AC
11. Click Save
12. If there were 2 entries for 'your network name' in your Network Connections list, proceed with next step, otherwise go to the last step.
13. Click on the other 'your network name' entry
14. Click Edit
15. Go to 'Wi-Fi' or 'Wireless' Tab
16. Click the BSSID Dropdown
17. Select the BSSID Matching the 5 Ghz Network (22:22:22:22:22:22 in this example) OR leave the BSSID empty if there are multiple other secondary access points
18. Switch to the 'General' Tab
19. Uncheck the checkbox that is labelled: 'Automatically connect to this network when it is available'
20. Set the 'Connection name' to [your network name]_N
21. Click Save...
22. Disconnect from your network and re-connect

You should now be connected to the 2.4Ghz network, and you would have to explicitly do the opposite process in order to connect to the 5 Ghz Network.

Comment: Thank you so much for this! I had tried something similar by connecting to a hidden network which did not work, but this approach did work. What threw me before is that there is no "Network Connections" in the main settings app. I found "Advanced Network Configuration" through the main OS search (Super/Windows button then start typing).

Of course this still doesn't answer the question but it was very useful for me nonetheless. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry I'm one year and five months late to this, but I had similar issues with AiMesh and my nine Google speakers so this might help if you apply part 1 to your laptop connection:

1. If you use Smart Connect this causes issues for Google speakers when the router decides to move them between 2.4Ghz and 5Ghz. To get round this, either turn off smart Connect which will create a separate network login for each fequency band, and stick to one band for the speakers. If you want to use Smart Connect (I do) then go on the browser version of the Asus Router software and select "Wireless" then use the "Wireless Mac Filter" tab to force the Google speakers to either the 5Ghz or 2.4Ghz bands. Currently I have them all on 2.4Ghz which involved setting a filter to reject 5Ghz and then allocating the speakers to this filter from the drop-down list, and then clicking 'apply'.
2. If you are using AiMesh, another thing that will cause problems with Google speakers is when the router reallocates a speaker from one node to another - which it might from time to time for load balancing. To stop this I used the Asus mobile app and set the speakers to bind to their nearest node, which stops them jumping. Take care to ensure any stereo pairs are bound to the same node, although speaker groups do work across multiple nodes.

It may be necessary to reboot the speakers and reassign them to any groups to set this up, but mine are all behaving well now, thankfully.

Hope this helps.

Regards

TobyC